# setSupportMultipleWindows and setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically not allowing popup for webView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, tabs

I am trying to allow a new window to be opened in a WebView when a button on a website is pressed.  I have tried enabling both `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically` and `setSupportMultipleWindows`, but still nothing happens when the button is pressed.

```
public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.webkit.WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        myWebView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://somewebsite.com/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        myWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

I have read and tried the suggested answers in the following:

- [android : Open pop-up window in my webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308601/android-open-pop-up-window-in-my-webview)

I *think* the reason the answer in the question linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308601/android-open-pop-up-window-in-my-webview) may not be working for my case because the linked question is talking about a popup within the same window, but the button I am clicking opens a new window entirely (which I cannot change).

**Does anyone why know why `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically` and `setSupportMultipleWindows` aren't doing the trick and how I can set up my webview so that it allows clicking a button that opens a new window?**

Comment: keep `window.open()` in your scripting side code.  and override `onCreateWindow` in `WebChromeClient` in android side

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308601/android-open-pop-up-window-in-my-webview), we had the same issue. 
`setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically`  and `setSupportMultipleWindows`  must be set on the Chrome Browser. Your code is using the **default** webview:

```
myWebView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
```

The webview must be extended to use chrome **setWebChromeClient**:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                    boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

                    // Add your settings to the chrome browser:
                    WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);
                    newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                    newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
           }
});
```