# I have built a WebView app but the popup under website not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Please help me I have developed a webview app in which I have added the Instagram link but I am not able to open that (+) sign to add images also on other websites so I am not able to open popup under any of the websites.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    AdView adView;
    Spinner spUrls;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar pb;
    TextView tvGo;
    long time=0;
    String[] urls;
    String url="https://facebook.com/";
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        cd=new ConnectionDetector(this);
        spUrls=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spUrls);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        tvGo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGo);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.msw_progress);

        urls=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.urls);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        if(cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress==0)
                    pb.setProgress(0);
                //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                /*setTitle("Loading...");
                setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                    setTitle(R.string.app_name);*/
            }
        });
        WebView wv=new WebView(this);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                  @Override
                                  public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                                      //Required functionality here
                                      return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                                  }
                              });
        adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-*******"); // Seems like you may be exposing your ad unit id to the public, may be better to keep this a secret or use the testing id found in the admob docs
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        tvGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                url=urls[spUrls.getSelectedItemPosition()];
                if(cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(WebviewActivity.this,"PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time)<2000){
                super.onBackPressed();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "PRESS AGAIN TO EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

here you can see my all code for webview please tell me solution as fast as you can

Comment: can you update your question with code related to WebView settings and webview loading?

Comment: Qustion Updated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try taking a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308601/android-open-pop-up-window-in-my-webview) Stack Overflow post about showing popups in a webview.

I think the key for you would be the following piece of code in that post:

```
WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.